# Get attribute from list in Python

Tags: python, list, attributes

This is probably very simple but i cant figure it out :(

Im trying to get the list of all captions form the list below

```
mylist = [{'Caption': 'obj1'},{'Caption': 'obj2'},{'Caption': 'obj3'}]
print(mylist)

captions = map(lambda o: o.Caption, mylist)
```

but im getting `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Caption'`

i can write the same in Ansible `{{ mylist | map(attribute='Caption')|list}}` but no idea in Python :(

Comment: `captions = map(lambda o: o["Caption"], mylist)` - this is python, not js. alternatively: `captions = map(lambda o: o.get("Caption"), mylist)`

Comment: You have a list of dictionaries. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops

Comment: Whats your expected output here? `map` will return a `map` object unless you cast it to `list` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `dict[key]` in python.

You can also use `.get(key)`.

```
captions = map(lambda o: o['Caption'], mylist)
captions = map(lambda o: o.get('Caption'), mylist)
```

If you are new to python, you can try reading this to learn about creating dicts, keys, accessing, iterating, and modifying.

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/dictionary-python

Also, note that `map` will return an iterator, you can call `list` on it to create a list from it.

```
list(map(...))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your example in `Ansible`/`jinja`.

To match your exact output from;

```
{{ mylist | map(attribute='Caption')|list}}
```

You will need to ensure you cast the `map()` iterator to a `list`.

```
captions = list(map(lamba o: o.get('Caption'), mylist))
```

`Ansible` returns a `list` when you specify `|list` after your `map()` where as pure `Python` returns a `map object`

```
>>> captions = map(lambda o: o['Caption'], mylist)
>>> captions
#<map object at 0x03BA5130>


>>> list(map(lambda o: o['Caption'], mylist))
#['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
To access keys from `dictionary` in python you either need to use .get(key) or dict[key] syntax.

```
mylist = [{'Caption': 'obj1'},{'Caption': 'obj2'},{'Caption': 'obj3'}]
print(mylist)

captions = map(lambda o: o.get('Caption'), mylist)
print(list(captions)) # Because map will return an iterator, so you have to call list on the iterator to create a list out of it.

captions = map(lambda o: o['Caption'], mylist)
print(list(captions)) # Because map will return an iterator, so you have to call list on the iterator to create a list out of it for printing
```